# Entity Framework in Visual Studio: database is not created with DbContext base constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I'm brand new to Visual Studio and .NET, and I'm following [this tutorial on Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/ASP-NET-tutorials/Code-first-development-Entity-Framework/158377/171749-4.html) (Code-first development with the Entity Framework) to create an ASP.NET MVC app where I should be able to add Tour objects to a database using a form.

I've created a class `MyDbContext` that inherits from `DbContext`.

I've added a base class constructor with the name of the database that needs to be created for this app when information is submitted from the form. I've also added a `DbSet` named `Tours` that holds the tour objects.

Here is that code, in *MyDBContext.cs*:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext() : base("ExploreCalifornia")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Tour> Tours { get; set; }
}
```

In the Tour Controller, I create an instance of `MyDbContext` named `db`:

```
private MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
```

I have a `Create` page that contains the form to add a new tour, and here is the POST route for this page:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Tour tour)
{
    try
    {
        db.Tours.Add(tour);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Following with the debugger, when I try to add a new tour, it skips over the `SaveChanges` line and goes directly into the catch block. No database is ever created, and nothing shows up under App_Data in the Solution Explorer.

The tutorial mentions that the database will be created using SQL Server Express LocalDB, but I don't see any reference to LocalDB in the Server Explorer. This is still new, so I'm a little lost on how to approach this.

Any ideas of what might be going wrong, or where to start looking?

Comment: Can you add the message of the exception you're getting?

Comment: change the line `catch {` to `catch (Exception ex) {` and set a breakpoint on `return View();` - you should then have some detail about the actual problem - at the moment you have no way of knowing what's going on at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing is, when you use DbContext's contructor with a string parameter, the parameter must be either
1. name of a connection string from your app.config or web.config in the form `name=MyConnectionString`. For instance, your config contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="your str here" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and you declare your context like this

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext() : base("name=MyConnectionString")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Tour> Tours { get; set; }
}
```

or
2. direct connection string, like this

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext() : base("Server=(local), Database=MyDBName, User=blah-blah...")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Tour> Tours { get; set; }
}
```

Please, take note that if you use a config file, it must be in your AppDomain directory (for exe it's its folder; for a web site it's the site's bin folder).